# Can I use HUD menu for unfocused applications?

Tags: unity, hud

Example: if I am running LibreOffice Writer on one desktop and Audacious on another, can I train or alter the Unity HUD Alt Command to allow me access to menu items in Audacious even as Writer is the focused window?

I did a little looking around, but I'm stumped. Fuzzy matching seems simply to allow access to focused windows at any given point, unless no windows are focused. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

***No, It isn't possible.***

Hud is made to replace traditional menu system. As you can't access a menu without bringing the application is focus, You can't do this also in Hud.

Have a look at [Mark Shuttleworth's](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/939) blog. It is saying

> **It covers the focused app (because that’s where you probably want to act) as well as system functionality**

Comment: I'd answer that on the desktop, while working in a focussed application, i can still access indicators. so let's say i want to make a screenshot of my focussed window. Why shouldn't i access my Shuuter Indicator using the HUD? Or even better: I'm writing a text with libreoffice and want to insert a snippet from my clipboard-manager-indicator. I can do that using the mouse without losing libreoffice it's focus. So following Mark's point, the HUD should access at least the indicators.